# Загрузка через Grub диска зашифрованного как plain

Tags: linux, grub

Как загрузить Linux с зашифрованного диска, при условии что он зашифрован через cryptsetup как plain, а не LUKS? Если просто указать параметр `crypt_root`, то возникает ошибка что не найден заголовок LUKS. Логично. А каким параметром дать знать что у меня не LUKS? Потратил не мало времени и ничего не нашёл: всё что относится к загрузке с зашифрованного диска - относится к LUKS :(

Дополнение: исходя из вики Arch'а - я пробовал использовать два параметра - `cryptdevice` и `crypto`. Второй, в виду того, что были использованы параметры по-умолчанию, я оставил пустым. Итого строка загрузки выглядит так:

```
linux-5.10.72-gentoo cryptdevice=/dev/sdb:ssd crypto=:::: root=/dev/mapper/ssd trim_root=yes ro
```

В таком варианте происходит безуспешная попытка найти /dev/mapper/ssd (запроса на расшифроку диска нет) и следует запрос на уточнение имени корневого раздела или переход в консоль. После того как я в консоли восстановления вручную расшифровываю диск командой `cryptsetup --allow-discards open /dev/sdb ssd --type plain` - загрузка успешно продолжается.

Comment: [вику арча](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Plain_dm-crypt) уже читал? если кратко, то надо указать шифр в виде типа `crypto=:aes-xts-plain64:512:0:` и расположение ключа с помощью `cryptkey`

Comment: Спасибо, прочитал. Я уже пробовал до этого использовать параметр `cryptdevice`, но вики арча говорит что так же должен быть указан параметр `crypto` (хотя может быть указан пустым). Обновил вопрос с деталями.

Comment: гмм... тогда я бы копал в сторону того, как именно initrd устроен в твоём дистрибутиве и где его погладить, чтобы он `cryptsetup`'у передал `plain`... возможно, имена некоторых параметров будут отличаться... для начала я бы попробовал распаковать образ initrd и `grep`'нуть его на предмет `cryptsetup`...